# Insert multiple rows Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to insert multiple dynamic rows to a table,

I have two tables.. 'students' and 'studentextend'..
with two primary keys (studentID in 'students) and (studentextendID in 'studentextend'), and table 'studentextend' has a field 'studentID' that is the primary key in 'students' table.

What i'm trying to do is, insert multiple rows dynamically into table 'studentextend', but each row has to have the same studentID and It's different from 'studentextendID' which is Auto increment, In other words, trying to assign multiple dynamic subject fields to one student.

But it's not inserting anything.

Controller:

```
$data=$this->input->post();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($data['subject']); $i++) {
    $studentExtendArray[] = array(
        'studentID' => $studentID,
        'subject' => $this->input->post('subject[$i]')
    );     
}
 $this->studentextend_m->insert_batch_studentextend($studentExtendArray);
```

---

Model

```
public function insert_batch_studentextend($array) {
    $id = parent::insert_batch($array);
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: are you using CI3 or CI4? CI4 is using insertBatch(), see [Inserting Data](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

Comment: @Vickel I already did see it, It's working if i'm using multiple arrays with static fields, but what im trying to do is, dynamically add them, based on how many fields the user filled.

Comment: then you need to explain a bit more what you are doing, as it is a bit hard to understand what you want to achieve without an example (input, expected output, current output/error). Please edit your Question (don't make edits in comments). Also looking into your code: don't execute the batch within your loop, **you need to take it out of the loop**. The loop is where you create the data you need for the the `insertBatch()`. If you opt do do updates within the loop, then just use `insert()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried what you suggested, and it's still not working, actually, there's no error, it just doesnt insert anything. and i also editted my post, hopefully it's more understandable now.

Comment: well start to debug with `echo "<pre>"; print_r($array); die;` maybe back to $data to see if you have any values to update...

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [studentID] => 164
            [subject] => 
        )

)`

That's the output after debugging, can't really figure out what's the issue. although it's not inserting the studentID in the table.

Comment: try following the docs with: `$db = \Config\Database::connect();
$builder = $db->table('yourtable');$builder->insertBatch($array);` (that is if you use CI4)